# Unable to update WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp

I'm unable to update WhatsApp on my Lumia 520. It says "Attention required", and when I tap on it, it says the same thing again.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Uninstall then re-install the app.

Comment: What does it tell you, when it says "attention required"?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Windows Phone 8.1? If so you need to move the Whatsapp application from your SD card to your phone storage (the new Whatsapp update doesn't support SD card for some reason).

To do this go to: Settings > Storage Sense > SD Card > Apps+games > Whatsapp > Move to Phone

Once you've done that you should have no trouble updating :)